# Javascript change CSS attribute background of nav (materializeCSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I have been trying to create a navigation bar using materializeCSS and want to have the background color change on scroll. For some reason I can't make this work. Since I am using MaterializeCSS, just adding and removing another class to the 'nav' doesn't work. I appreciate your assistance on this.

HTML

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Web</a>
    <a href="#" data-target="mobile-nav" class="sidenav-trigger">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></div>
    </a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
```

For sure there is some error or something I have to do different in the below.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop()>200){
        $("nav").css('background','#000');
      }else{
        $("nav").css('background','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Did you include `jQuery` ?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or equivalent, and just update your post with the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var bgcolor = ($(window).scrollTop()>200)?'#000':'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)';
      $("nav").css('background-color', bgcolor);
    });
  });
```

From http://api.jquery.com/css/
Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background, border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.